# Difference in days between two dates one of which is user's input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing an 'age to seconds' converter, but I keep getting various errors.

```
#

!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#This program converts your age to seconds
from datetime import datetime

print ('Welcome to a simple age to seconds converter. ')

def get_date():
    print ('Please enter the year of your birth in the format YYYY, MM, DD:')
    date_of_birth = str(input())
    converted_date = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, '%Y, %m, %d')
    date_now = datetime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    total_seconds = ((date_now - converted_date).days)*86400
    return ('You have lived for:', total_seconds, 'seconds.')

print (get_date())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I think this is the most correct version of the program, but I keep getting an error TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' requires a 'datetime.date' object but received a 'str'.

Does anyone know how I can correct that? And also how to count seconds to the precise moment of inputting the date to now?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you attempting to call `main`? You haven't defined a `main` in that script. BTW, there are 86400 seconds in one day.

Answer (score 1):

`date_now` should be`datetime.now()`. `strftime("%Y-%m-%d")` is called on an existing `datetime` instance and returns a string.

```
date_of_birth = input()
converted_date = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, '%Y, %m, %d')
date_now = datetime.now()
total_seconds = (date_now - converted_date).days * 24 * 60 * 60
# day: 24 h * 60 min * 60 sec = 86400 != 8640000
print('You have lived for:', total_seconds, 'seconds.')
```

Comment: Because the OP did and didn't cause any harm :) updated.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the method strftime() straight from the class, which instead should be called on a datetime instance. I've added the .now() in the code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#This program converts your age to seconds
from datetime import datetime

print ('Welcome to a simple age to seconds converter. ')

def get_date():
    print ('Please enter the year of your birth in the format YYYY, MM, DD:')
    date_of_birth = str(input())
    converted_date = datetime.strptime(date_of_birth, '%Y, %m, %d')
    date_now = datetime.now()
    total_seconds = ((date_now - converted_date).days)*8640000
    return ('You have lived for:', total_seconds, 'seconds.')

print (get_date())
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Edit: I just realized that the next line in your code might actually generate an error, because then a datetime instance is subtracted from a string. You might want to remove the .strftime() call entirely.

Comment: You are subtracting a `datetime` from a `str` object.